# How to create a catchment area using LSOA and point file data

Tags: geoprocessing, catchment-area

I have to create a catchment area (based on LSOA) for the 19 underground stations within Camden borough and it has to be in a polygon vector file. I know I have to somehow group the SOAs but don’t know which geoprocessing tool to use.

Comment: What software do you use or can use? Do you have a road network data?

Comment: Can you define LSOA & SOA, please?

Answer (score 1):

This can be calculated quite easily using Voronoi Diagrams (also known as Theissen polygons) based on Euclidean Distance metrics (i.e. "As the crow flies") in [GRASS](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.voronoi.html), [QGIS](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/), or [ArcGIS](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001m000000). In all three of these platforms, the linked tools take as input a point feature class and output a polygon feature class.

If you are trying to calculate based on travel time (i.e. drive time), the problem becomes more difficult. See [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64297/constructing-a-voronoi-diagram-using-a-complicated-travel-time-metric) for more information if that is your case.